# dnsmasq, one host on multiple vlans

Tags: dhcp, vlan, dnsmasq

I have `dnsmasq` configured to serve static dhcp on two networks; one on the primary interface and one on a vlan attached to the primary interface. The interface config looks like this:

```
3: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 172.16.0.1/24 brd 172.16.0.255 scope global noprefixroute enp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
13: enp2s0.200@enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 172.16.1.1/24 brd 172.16.1.255 scope global noprefixroute enp2s0.200
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

And `dnsmasq.conf` looks like:

```
log-dhcp
log-facility=-
dhcp-range=172.16.0.1,static
dhcp-range=172.16.1.1,static
dhcp-leasefile=/dnsmasq/leases
dhcp-hostsdir=/dnsmasq/hosts
dhcp-authoritative
```

I have another host on the same network that has a similar interface configuration: one interface on the native VLAN, and one interface on VLAN 200. I have set a pair of static addresses for this host in
`/dnsmasq/hosts/52:54:00:e1:e6:4b` like this:

```
52:54:00:e1:e6:4b,172.16.0.73,10m
52:54:00:e1:e6:4b,172.16.1.63,10m
```

When the first interface on the host comes up, I see in the
`dnsmasq` logs:

```
dnsmasq-dhcp[6]: 3876724415 available DHCP subnet: 172.16.0.1/255.255.255.0
dnsmasq-dhcp[6]: 3876724415 DHCPREQUEST(enp2s0) 172.16.0.73 52:54:00:e1:e6:4b
dnsmasq-dhcp[6]: 3876724415 tags: known, enp2s0
dnsmasq-dhcp[6]: 3876724415 DHCPACK(enp2s0) 172.16.0.73 52:54:00:e1:e6:4b
```

That's what I expect. But when the *second* interface comes up, I see:

```
dnsmasq-dhcp[6]: 2375610969 available DHCP subnet: 172.16.1.1/255.255.255.0
dnsmasq-dhcp[6]: 2375610969 DHCPREQUEST(enp2s0.200) 172.16.1.63 52:54:00:e1:e6:4b
dnsmasq-dhcp[6]: 2375610969 DHCPNAK(enp2s0.200) 172.16.1.63 52:54:00:e1:e6:4b wrong address
...
dnsmasq-dhcp[6]: 367379373 available DHCP subnet: 172.16.1.1/255.255.255.0
dnsmasq-dhcp[6]: 367379373 DHCPDISCOVER(enp2s0.200) 172.16.1.63 52:54:00:e1:e6:4b
dnsmasq-dhcp[6]: 367379373 tags: known, enp2s0.200
dnsmasq-dhcp[6]: 367379373 DHCPOFFER(enp2s0.200) 172.16.1.63 52:54:00:e1:e6:4b
...
dnsmasq-dhcp[6]: 367379373 DHCPREQUEST(enp2s0.200) 172.16.1.63 52:54:00:e1:e6:4b
dnsmasq-dhcp[6]: 367379373 tags: known, enp2s0.200
dnsmasq-dhcp[6]: 367379373 DHCPACK(enp2s0.200) 172.16.1.63 52:54:00:e1:e6:4b
```

The initial `DHCPDISCOVER` results in a `DHCPNAK`, presumably because
there's already a lease for the given MAC address.  But that lease is
on a different network, so this behavior seems erroneous.

And now when the first interface renews, it will go through the same
`DISCOVER/NAK/DISCOVER/OFFER/REQUEST/ACK` sequence.

What is the correct way of configuring things to serve different
leases to the same MAC address when it shows up on different networks?